# Hibernate : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am using hibernate to handle database transactions. I am new in hibernate.

I have to entities :

- AttributeEntity
- TaxonomyEntity

**AttributeEntity can have one or more taxonomyEntities.**

**AttributeEntity constraints:**

- attributeId is the primary key
- attributeCd is unique

**TaxonomyEntity constraints:**

- taxonomyId is the primary key
- attributeCd is the foreign key to the table "Attribute"

**What am I trying to do?**

Create the relationships between these two entities so that if I can create/delete the whole tree structure ( Attribue and it's taxonomies). Like attributeEntity.save() or attributeEntity.delete()

**The problem:**

Using the test below, when I am trying to save the attributeEntity,hibernate saves the data. But when using a list of taxonomyEntity as part of AttributeEntity, I am seeing the error described below. **May I get any insight on the reason of the error?**

**My AttributeEntity class:**

```
package com.myplace.online.attribute.api.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@SequenceGenerator( name = "attribute_seq", sequenceName = "OAP_META_NEW.ATTRIBUTE_SEQ" )
@Table(name = "ATTRIBUTE", schema = "OAP_META_NEW")
public class AttributeEntity implements Serializable
{
    private int attributeId;
    private Integer attributeCategoryId;
    private String attributeName;
    private String attributeCd;

    private List<TaxonomyEntity> taxonomyEntities;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "attribute_seq" )
    public int getAttributeId()
    {
        return attributeId;
    }

    public void setAttributeId( int attributeId )
    {
        this.attributeId = attributeId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_ID", nullable = false, precision = 0)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY_ID")
    public Integer getAttributeCategoryId()
    {
        return attributeCategoryId;
    }

    public void setAttributeCategoryId( Integer attributeCategoryId )
    {
        this.attributeCategoryId = attributeCategoryId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_NAME", nullable = false, length = 70)
    public String getAttributeName()
    {
        return attributeName;
    }

    public void setAttributeName( String attributeName )
    {
        this.attributeName = attributeName;
    }


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_CD", nullable = false, length = 6)
    public String getAttributeCd()
    {
        return attributeCd;
    }

    public void setAttributeCd( String attributeCd )
    {
        this.attributeCd = attributeCd;
    }




    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn( name = "ATTRIBUTE_CD", referencedColumnName = "ATTRIBUTE_CD", nullable = false )
    public List<TaxonomyEntity> getTaxonomyEntities()
    {
        return taxonomyEntities;
    }

    public void setTaxonomyEntities(List<TaxonomyEntity> taxonomyEntities)
    {
        this.taxonomyEntities = taxonomyEntities;
    }


}
```

**My TaxonomyEntity class**

```
package com.myplace.online.attribute.api.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@SequenceGenerator( name = "taxonomy_seq", sequenceName = "OAP_META_NEW.TAXONOMY_SEQ" )
@Table(name = "TAXONOMY", schema = "OAP_META_NEW")
public class TaxonomyEntity implements Serializable
{
    private int taxonomyId;
    private String attributeCd;
    private String taxonomyCategory;
    private String taxonomySubcategory;
    private String taxonomyAttributeName;


    @Id
    @Column(name = "TAXONOMY_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "taxonomy_seq" )
    public int getTaxonomyId()
    {
        return taxonomyId;
    }

    public void setTaxonomyId( int taxonomyId )
    {
        this.taxonomyId = taxonomyId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ATTRIBUTE_CD", length = 6,  nullable = false, insertable = false ,updatable = false)
    public String getAttributeCd() 
    {
        return attributeCd;
    }

    public void setAttributeCd( String attributeCd ) 
    {
        this.attributeCd = attributeCd;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TAXONOMY_CATEGORY", nullable = true, length = 100)
    public String getTaxonomyCategory() 
    {
        return taxonomyCategory;
    }

    public void setTaxonomyCategory( String taxonomyCategory ) 
    {
        this.taxonomyCategory = taxonomyCategory;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TAXONOMY_SUBCATEGORY", nullable = true, length = 100)
    public String getTaxonomySubcategory() 
    {
        return taxonomySubcategory;
    }

    public void setTaxonomySubcategory( String taxonomySubcategory ) 
    {
        this.taxonomySubcategory = taxonomySubcategory;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "TAXONOMY_ATTRIBUTE_NAME", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getTaxonomyAttributeName() 
    {
        return taxonomyAttributeName;
    }

    public void setTaxonomyAttributeName( String taxonomyAttributeName ) 
    {
        this.taxonomyAttributeName = taxonomyAttributeName;
    }


}
```

**This is the way I am trying to test:**

```
    //create attribute
    attributeEntity = new AttributeEntity();
    attributeEntity.setAttributeCategoryId(0);
    attributeEntity.setAttributeCd("E_TEST");
    attributeEntity.setAttributeId(0);
    attributeEntity.setAttributeName("TEST_ATTRIBUTE");

    //Create Taxomony
    taxonomyEntity = new TaxonomyEntity();
   // taxonomyEntity.setTaxonomyId(0); -- expecting this to be created by the sequence
    taxonomyEntity.setDescription("A test taxonomy");
    taxonomyEntity.setTaxonomyCategory("123123123CategoryTest");
    taxonomyEntity.setTaxonomySubcategory("123123123SubcategoryTest");
   // taxonomyEntity.setAttributeCd(attributeEntity.getAttributeCd()); -- Expecting this to be created from AttributeEntity
    taxonomyEntity.setTaxonomyAttributeName("TEST_TAXONOMY_ATTRIBUTE");


    List<TaxonomyEntity> taxonomyList = new ArrayList<TaxonomyEntity>();
    taxonomyList.add(taxonomyEntity);

    attributeEntity.setTaxonomyEntities(taxonomyList);

    attributeService = context.getBean( AttributeService.class );
    attributeService.saveAttributeEntity(attributeEntity);
```

**This is the error I am seeing :**

- IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.myplace.online.attribute.api.entities.AttributeEntity.attributeCd
- and then towards the end :  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class

  ```
  org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of com.myplace.online.attribute.api.entities.AttributeEntity.attributeCd


  at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:192)
  at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValue(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:76)
  at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValues(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:82)
  at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.getPropertyValues(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:107)
  at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValues(ComponentType.java:433)
  at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.getPropertyValues(ComponentType.java:421)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processComponent(WrapVisitor.java:135)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:127)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.WrapVisitor.processValue(WrapVisitor.java:125)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.visitCollectionsBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:372)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:273)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:114)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:684)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:676)
  at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:235)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:379)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:319)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:296)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
  at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:460)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:294)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:137)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
  at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)
  at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)
  at com.myplace.online.attribute.api.dao.GenericDAOImpl.save(GenericDAOImpl.java:85)
  at com.myplace.online.attribute.api.services.AttributeServiceImpl.saveAttributeEntity(AttributeServiceImpl.java:41)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
  at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
  at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.saveAttributeEntity(Unknown Source)
  at com.myplace.online.attribute.api.TaxonomyTest.setUpEntity(TaxonomyTest.java:97)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
  at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
  at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
  at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
  at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
  at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
  at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
  at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
  at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
  **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class**
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicGetter.get(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:169)
  ```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"attributeCd" was foreign key in ATTRIBUTE table but was not primary key in TAXONOMY table. Hibernate does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of definning OneToMany in Hibernate

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="entitie")
@OrderBy("theFieldYouWantOrder ASC")
```

> Lists can be mapped in two different ways:
>   as ordered lists, where the order is not materialized in the database
>   as indexed lists, where the order is materialized in the database
>   To order lists in memory, add @javax.persistence.OrderBy to your
>   property. This annotation takes as parameter a list of comma separated
>   properties (of the target entity) and orders the collection
>   accordingly (eg firstname asc, age desc), if the string is empty, the
>   collection will be ordered by the primary key of the target entity.

[The documentation of Hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html) check Section 7.2.2 for the full documentation. And I think the error you are Trying to map like ManyToOne instead of OneToMany